# How to use Material Web Components in electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, material-design

I'm trying to use the google designer stuff in my application made on electron.

but even installing I can't use the style of the designer material

I installed the package using

```
npm i material-components-web
```

My code is as follows:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <title>MyTestApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="win">
      <div>
        <img src="bacground.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="Panel">
          <div class="Test"></div>
            <mwc-textfield class="TextFiledTest" label="Test" icon="event"></mwc-textfield>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone who has used material web components in electron tell me how can I do it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The default content security policy block loading of third party resources. Also, since you already installed `npm` module for material web components you can load them locally.

To fix this issue:

1. Update your content security policy header to enable loading the material icon font.

```
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self';
      script-src 'self';
      font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
      style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com"
    />
```

2. Use the scripts and styles from installed node modules:

```
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <script src="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```

3. Also add a local CSS file to fix user agent styles with:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
 }
 * { box-sizing: border-box }
```